# Is it unacceptable to vote elsewhere when feeling the need to vote twice? Why?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, votes, up-votes

At time users may show strong opinion of a post, and comment that they feel they would like to vote twice. Would it be appropriate to locate at random another post of this same user and give an additional vote of that same kind? For example, I thought an answer deserves five votes, so I’d go and vote five other posts.

The essence of this question is that if I feel a user has been showed a lack of votes can I [or should I] compensate elsewhere?

---

This post ensuing [this thread](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50312413#50312413)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please don't. Voting on a post should have absolutely nothing to do with who wrote it or its current score and entirely to do with its current content.

If you want to reward an answer that went above and beyond, you can offer a bounty. There is an existing bounty reason to "reward an existing answer".

Comment: However there’s no alternative for the inverse

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel you can downvote (once), and if you think you can, you can try to improve the post so it no longer warrants the downvote.  Or you can downvote and move on.  But doing what you propose breaks the model of the site and is called "targeted voting", which is a no-no.

Comment: @DrShmuel in the end of the day any one person is not supposed to be in charge of getting the post or person to the right total score. That would never work. You do your your part and move on and the system evens out in the long run. If you want to affect the score advocate for what's good or bad about it to others in a comment or in chat.

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you. Although I should say this question was really just continued discussion from the thread I saw in the chat, in order to clarify the matter.